# Drop the entire row if a particular sub-row does not fulfill condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas df with subentries. I would like to make a condition for a particular subentry, and if this condition is not fulfilled, I would like to drop the entire row so I could update the df.

For example, I would like to check each subentry 0 for all the entries and give a condition that if pt<120 then drop the entire entry.

```
               pt
entry subentry
0     0        100
      1        200
      2        300
1     0        200
      1        300
2     0        80
      1        300
      3        400
      4        300
...   ...      ...
```

So, the entry 0 and 2 (with all the subentries) should be deleted.

```
               pt
entry subentry
1     0        200
      1        300
...   ...      ...
```

I tried using:

```
df.loc[(slice(None), 0), :]["pt"]>100
```

but it creates a new series and I cannot pass it to the original df because it does not match the entries/subentries. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
# Count the number of invalid `pt` per `entry`
invalid = df['pt'].lt(120).groupby(df['entry']).sum()

# Valid `entry` are those whose `invalid` count is 0
df[df['entry'].isin(invalid[invalid == 0].index)]
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, the "pt" is not on the same level as "entry" and "subentry". I modified my initial post. When I load a df, it automatically creates the "entry" and "subentry" so I think it is multidimensional index. The "pt" is a feature that I have an access to. Sorry and thank you, I will try to use your code.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to groupby "entry" and then calculate using `transform` to create a minimum that can then be used with `loc` to index the correct rows

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'entry': [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2], 
           'subentry': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2], 
           'pt': [100, 300, 200, 300, 80, 300]})
```

Initial df:

```
   entry  subentry   pt
0      0         1  100
1      0         2  300
2      1         1  200
3      1         2  300
4      2         1   80
5      2         2  300
```

Use loc to find select only the rows matching conditional:

```
df.loc[df.groupby('entry').transform('min')['pt']>120]
```

Output:

```
   entry  subentry   pt
2      1         1  200
3      1         2  300
```

Comment: Entry and subentry are not on the same level as "pt" (I modified my initial post). But thank you, I will try to use your way.

Comment: this solution is a good one. Just add ```df = df.reset_index(drop=True).ffill(axis=0)``` before  @bkeesey's code.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't want to flatten my initial df. I cannot get it because I don't really know how to do it on the multi-index dataframe.

Comment: Could you explain why my solution doesn't work on a multi-index? I created the multi-index by running `df = df.set_index(['entry', 'subentry'])` for my inital df. The solution still worked for me.